# Dotnetnuke - Dynamically change logo on Portal dependant on user or security role

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am fairly new to dotnetnuke and csharp, an was wondering what the easiest way to basically dynamically change the default logo dependant on the user or security role.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Alec

Answer (score 0):

The default DNN setting (Admin-> Site settings) allows you to set one logo for your site.
You would need to write some code, probably modify the skin, to achieve what you want